# How to look Gunicorn logs when it running?

Tags: heroku, logging, flask, server, gunicorn

I deployed a **Flask** application to a VPS, and using **Gunicorn** as a web server.
And I running the **Gunicorn** server using this command:

`gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 run:app --access-logfile '-'`

With the command I can see the log running. But after I closed my terminal session, I want to see the running logs again.

In Heroku I can use `heroku logs -t` to do that, any similar way to see it on Gunicorn..?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up the supervisor. Supervisor keeps your server running mode and saves your log. setup the supervisor file below and then you can see the logs:

```
[program:your_project_name]
command=/home/your_virualenv/bin/gunicorn --log-level debug 
run_apiengine:main_app --bind 0.0.0.0:5007 --workers 2 --worker-class gevent
directory=your_project_directory
stdout_logfile= your_log_folder_path/supervisor_stdout.log
stderr_logfile= your_log_folder_path/supervisor_stderr.log
user=your_user
autostart=true
PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:your_python_path";OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT='1';
```